# Tabchange first occurs second time - C#

Tags: c#

First time posting here! :D

I got a function in C#.

```
 else if (cbFilter1.SelectedTab == cbFilter1.TabPages["Filtre"]) //your specific tabname
 {
     if (cbFilter11.Checked == true)
     {
         this.btnFilter1_Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);
     }
```

And the code actually works fine, but my problem is that, the first time i change the Tab, nothing happens, but if i change tab again, and jump back the function runs. So it seems like that the functions does not run the first time i click the tab "Filtre", but it runs the second time.

Any way to prevent this, so it runs the first time aswell?

Regards
Matias

Updated: 
The code starts here:

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,      
EventArgs e)
{
```

And I've made the same thing to another tabpage, inside same page which works:

```
if (cbFilter1.SelectedTab == cbFilter1.TabPages["Halvårlig"]) //your specific tabname
{
    //this.btnFørsteHalvår_Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    btnFørsteHalvår.PerformClick();
}
```

But when i insert another IF inside a tabchange, it only works on second "visit".

Comment: Don't call events, they are triggered automatically. Call methods like `Filter` that you can use from wherever you like, for example from `btnFilter1_Click` or from above code.

Comment: Well, was because i am launching a click event from a button, and all the other methods which i tried, did not work. The first thing i got working, was this. I do know, that there a smarter ways, but will require me to change quite some methods. But just now i got this other problem :/

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but instead of calling the event handler, try doing `btnFilter1.PerformClick()`.

Comment: also you need to tell us where are you putting this code...

Comment: Same problem - The functions runs the second time i "visit" the tab. Its like it does not run the above code, the first time i click on the tab, but if i change tab, and go back, then it runs.

Comment: Out of interest is your "Filtre" tab selected to start with? And where is your code? Is it in a SelectionChanged event handler for your tab control?

Comment: Updated the description - hopefully its a little more easy to understand now :)

Comment: What is the first selected tab when your application is loaded or your tab control is first displayed? I have a sneaking suspicion that it is your "Filtre" tab which means you won't receive the SelectionChanged event until a different tab has been selected.

Comment: My first selected default tab, is not inside this functions, as it runs differently. But the first tab inside SelecttionChanged Event is this: 
`if (cbFilter1.SelectedTab == cbFilter1.TabPages["Kvartal"]) `
`{`
`this.kvartal_1_Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);`
`}`

And this works correct. It loads data on first "visit".

Comment: No when you first see the Tab control in your application which Tab is selected?

Comment: cbFilter1 is the default tab, and first selected, when the program runs. The strange behavior is that it works, without the additional "IF". But i need the additional if to check for checkboxes, before i can load data.

Comment: Which additional if? This one "if (cbFilter11.Checked == true)" ? If so what actually is cbFilter11 and how is it being Checked on the second time round?